# Communication between master and detail view controllers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using Xcode 4.3.3 and Storyboards for this project.

I have a master view controller that drills down a couple of levels with a navigation controller until it gets to a list. When the user selects a cell from that list, I want the detail view controller to change to a new view controller. Then when the user navigates back to the top of the master view controller, I want the the detail view controller to pop off and show the original one again.

I can get it somewhat working using segues but it becomes very confusing trying to get the new detail view controller to pop off and show the original one. It also messes up my BarButtonItemPresenter delegate that controls the master view popover in portrait mode. Is there a way to do this programmatically? If so, example code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a segue from the master view controller to the detail view controller. In the attributes inspector set the "Destination" to "Detail Split" and set the "Identifier" to something that makes sense (I used "Show Customer"). Then call this in your master view controller...

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Show Customer" sender:self];
    [self setDelegate:(id<CustomerTableViewControllerDelegate>)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]];
//call some method here to prepare your detail view controller
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer's a bit late, and your question is a little confusing, but...

I see you've tagged uiSplitViewController. I was stumped for a while trying to pop a View controller in iPad, this won't work.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Try instead:

```
[self.detailViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The split view controller on the iPad seems to use a second navigation controller, keep this in mind.

Sorry if I'm off track with the answer.